# Reducing execution time for a python program

Tags: python, c++, csv, automation

The following is code that I used to do a task. the code runs fine but takes over 2 minutes to get executed. And this is with only one rule (Rule_1), the rule is checked using an .exe ( written in CPP).Actually there are many CSV files that are needed to pass through the rules.

My question is will the program always use this much amount of time, because I have to implement more the 50 rule for the files, or there is any other way around?

```
import os
import fnmatch
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError
import sys
from shutil import copyfileobj


def locate(pattern, root="Z:/Automation/"):
    '''Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below
    supplied root directory.'''
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)


csv_path_unrefined = []
for xml in locate("*.csv"):
    try:
        ElementTree.parse(xml)
    except (SyntaxError, ExpatError):
        csv_path_unrefined.append(xml)
csv_path = []
for paths in csv_path_unrefined:
    if "results" in str(paths):
        csv_path.append(paths)


def check_rule1(path):
    # path = "PWLLOGGER_DEMO.csv"
    file = 'ConsoleApplication9.exe "' + path + '"'
   # print(file)
    details = os.popen(file).read()
    log_file = open("logs/Rule_1.txt")
    state = log_file.read()
    with open('results/Rule_1_log.log', 'a+') as files:
        files.write("\n========" + path + "========\n")
        files.close
    with open('results/Rule_1_log.log', 'a+') as output, open('logs/Rule_1.txt', 'r') as input:
        copyfileobj(input, output)
    if "failed" in state:
        return False
    else:
        return True


rule_1_passed = []
rule_1_failed = []

for paths in csv_path:
    result_r1 = check_rule1(paths)
    # print(result_r1)
    if result_r1 == False:
        rule_1_failed.append(paths)
        #print("Rule 1 has failed for " + paths)
    elif result_r1 == True:
        rule_1_passed.append(paths)
        #print("Rule 1 has passed for " + paths)
    open('logs/Rule_1.txt', 'w').close()


print(rule_1_failed)
print(rule_1_passed)
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Stack Overflow's sister site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Spawning a separate process carries a lot of overhead, so you probably want either: port the rule from C++ to python, or port your engine to C++.

In either case, if you can have your rules embedded in your code, you'll save that overhead.

In any event, don't take my word for it. Find a good profiling tool, measure where your time is going, and act accordingly.

Comment: @burlyearly I cannot do that because the rules written in C++ is written by a different developer, he just send me the exe(s) when done and my task is to fire these in python. Actually we are using python here for automation and mailing  purpose.

Comment: It looks like you're on windows. I'd suggest trying to negotiate a change in architecture where the other developer gives you DLLs rather than executables so that the rules are effectively just functions.

Again, though, you really need to profile this to make sure that your problem is overhead from loading the program and not some other unexpected issue. In my experience, time is spent where I *guess* it's spent in only about 60% of cases. 40% is a big enough number to justify breaking out a profiler.

Comment: @burlyearly Thanks for the suggestion.